Switching between battery and charger
I have the battery and charger. The essence of this simple circuit is that the device (in our case, the LED) is powered by the charger when it is active, and by the battery when it is not. The battery will always have a lower voltage than the charger. The question is, what can be done in this setup so that, by simply switching a button, the charger starts charging the battery while simultaneously powering the LED? Can I connect the positive wire in front of the diodes, as indicated in the circuit, to achieve this? If so, I also want this switch to turn on automatically when the battery voltage reaches 12V and turn off after a certain period. How difficult is this to implement, and what is required?

It is presumed that a lead acid battery is used.

The switch S1 is to be removed.
The charging current limiter R1 and the LED current limiter R2 are to be added.
The 1N4148 diodes are to be replaced with Schottky diodes having very
low forward voltage drop.



I'm using a 4s lifepo4 battery pack, so 14.6v is what I need. Also, I planned to use Schottky diodes and instead of an LED, a dc-dc converter is actually used. Sorry, I should have been more specific

But to switch modes should I place a switch instead of R1?

@Delete, You need to limit the current when charging the battery. If your "Charger" actually is a constant voltage power supply, then the current that would flow when you directly connect it to the battery is undefined. Vu2nan added R1 to limit the charging current. A better idea would be to use an actual "smart" battery charger instead of using a constant-voltage power brick.

@solomon-slow, It's not just a DC power source, it's a really smart charger for the 4s lifepo4 battery pack. The relevant question here is whether it will also correctly power devices connected in parallel in this case. (buck boost DC-DC is used between them)

@Delete, What do you mean, "buck boost DC-DC is used between them?" That's not shown in your diagram. If "Charger 14.5V" is the output of a DC to DC converter, then that's the "constant voltage power supply" that I was warning you about. A "smart charger" should be directly connected to the battery. Connecting a load while the battery is charging is a common practice, but if you want to know how large the load can be without interfering with the charger's "algorithm," then that's probably a question you should ask the charger manufacturer's tech support people.

@solomon-slow, Yes, I should have been more specific when creating the circuit. In fact, instead of an LED, a DC-DC converter is used, which in turn powers the devices I need. I decided to simplify the circuit by choosing an LED as an example of a load, but it seems I just confused everyone
